# Gitlab CI : get all commit changes from the push/merge

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I would like to have the files that have changed since the last push.

Currently I can find the difference on the last commit. However if I have several commits in one push, only the last commit is taken into account :

```sh
git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r ${CI_COMMIT_SHA} | while read FILE ; do
    infra="$(echo ${FILE} | cut -d'/' -f1)";
    application="$(echo ${FILE} | cut -d'/' -f2)";
    project="$(echo ${FILE} | cut -d'/' -f3)";

    if [[ " ${seen[*]} " == *"$project"* ]]
    then
        echo "Project ${project} has already been sync"
        continue
    fi

    seen+=($project)

    if [[ ! -d "${SCRIPT_DIR}/${infra}" ]] || [[ ! -d "${SCRIPT_DIR}/${infra}/${application}" ]] || [[ ! -d "${SCRIPT_DIR}/${infra}/${application}/${project}" ]]
    then
        echo "${SCRIPT_DIR}/${infra}/${application}/${project} not a valid folder"
        continue
    fi

    pushd ${SCRIPT_DIR}/${infra}/${application}/${project}
    echo "Auto delivery ${project}"
    bash delivery.sh auto

    retVal=$?
    if [ $retVal -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "Error (code $retVal) : check rsync return"
        exit 1
    fi
    popd

done
```

In the <kbd>delivery.sh</kbd> I do an rsync on the folder that was changed in the last commit (${CI_COMMIT_SHA}). However I would like to take into account ALL the folders in the last push/MR, not just the commit.

Is this possible ?

Comment: This workflow seems a bit brittle. What should happen if, for some reason, `delivery.sh` failed on one push. Then you fix the problem that made `delivery.sh` fail in the next commit and push it. Should `delivery.sh` then look at just the last commit, or also redo the previous one it had failed on? It would seem safer to me to design `delivery.sh` to do its analysis based on the current snapshot, not just the most recent changes.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm not aware of a way to do what you're asking, although there's probably a server-side equivalent to the reflog in GitLab.

Comment: @joanis I've added more code to the question. To answer your questions : ```delivery.sh``` is an rsync command (more complex than just one folder). I would like to know if I can have a push_id instead of ```${CI_COMMIT_SHA}```. Because actually, if I do two commits in a push, only the last one will be in ```${CI_COMMIT_SHA}``` and then, only the last one will be sync

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to user git diff with `^!` :

```sh
git diff --no-commit-id --name-only -r ${CI_COMMIT_SHA}^!
```

With `^!` parameter it will watch the difference with the parent commit.

Comment: How about merge request? The answer can only solve the problem when the action is `push`.